# Bokeh interactive scatter plot with 1M+ points

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

I created a bokeh interactive plot that displays two scatter plot with a crosshair linked between them, so that the position of the cursor in one plot is shown in the other. I am trying to plot a dataset that contains around 2 million points. When plotting, the cursor is staggering and takes some seconds to update.

The priority is to preserve the linked crosshair between the plots and make its movement smoother.

Is there any way to optimize this, so that the cursor movement is smoother?
Could some change in settings allow for more space allocated to the python script?
Could a different library serve the same purpose?

I tried resampling the data to only a third of the data points, however the problem still persists and the map displayed is not as clear.

Comment: One thing you can try is the [WebGL](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/output/webgl.html#webgl-acceleration) backend, if you don't use it already. This is made for larger data sets. But I am not sure if this solves your problem entirely.

Comment: since you asked for different libraries.. [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org) can do the job.... there's even a crosshair example in the docs [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/cursor_demo.html)